# Variables not being updated consistently when onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm trying to create cookies that saves the users search filters (as you can see, we have 3 dropdowns), such that if they move away from the domain, and head back within the last 30 minutes, they will have their last search filters already ready to fire an AJAX. Below is the code for for the dropdowns.

```
  <span id="category_filter" class="filter-select" data-target="filter_categories" data-curr_filter="communities">
  Communities &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</span></label>
<label>filter by
  <span id="topic_filter" class="filter-select" data-cat="" data-target="filter_topics" data-curr_filter="affordability" data-curr_filter_id="47">
  Affordability &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</span></label>
<label>sort by
  <span id="sort_by_filter" class="filter-select" data-target="filter_sort" data-curr_filter="created_at">
  Most recent &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</span></label>
```

An onclick function that targets ('.filter-list > li') is used, and here is some of the code.  What it does is replace the of the dropdown with the selected list element (e.g. Buy vs Rent, Neighbourhoods, Most Views, respectively), and changes the data-curr_filter on the dropdown:

```
(document).on(
    'click',
    '.filter-list > li',
    function() {
      var $text = $(this).text();
      var $val = $(this).data('val');
      var $parent_target = $(this).parent().attr('id');
      var $sortByFilter = null;
      var $topicFilter = null;

      if ($(this).parent('#filter_sort').length) {
        var thissort = $(this).data('val');
        $('.topic-search')
          .find('[data-target="' + $parent_target + '"]')
          .html($text + ' &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>')
          .attr('data-curr_filter', $val);
        $sortByFilter = thissort;
      } else {
        $sortByFilter = $('#sort_by_filter').data('curr_filter');
      }

      //cookie business
      var cookieCatFilter = $('#category_filter').data('curr_filter');
      var cookieTopicFilter = $('#topic_filter').data('curr_filter');
      var cookieSortFilter = $('#sort_by_filter').data('curr_filter');
      console.log(cookieCatFilter);
      console.log(cookieTopicFilter);
      console.log(cookieSortFilter);;

      var d = new Date();
      d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 30);
      var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();

      document.cookie = "catFilter=" + cookieCatFilter + "; " + expires + "; path=/";
      document.cookie = "topicFilter=" + cookieTopicFilter + "; " + expires + "; path=/";
      document.cookie = "sortFilter=" + cookieSortFilter + "; " + expires + "; path=/";
      // end of cookie business
```

However, what's happening is that more often than not, the console log is almost always stuck on the default filters in the first code-snippet.  After changing the '#topic_filter' or '#sort_by_filter', it logs the previous '#category_filter' and #topic_filter (always lagging behind).  Changing the #sort_by_filter never causes an update in data-curr_filter.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd say that this is a problem with JS being asynchronous. Can you put `setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log(cookieCatFilter);
        console.log(cookieTopicFilter);
        console.log(cookieSortFilter);
    }, 3000); ` in between the first, second and third blocks of code? This will delay it slightly allowing variables to change before functions are run. You can also check variable values are changing before functions run.

Comment: Ooh I did 2000, but I never tried any higher. Will let you know how it goes!

Comment: I tried delaying the actual assignment of the variables to be within the timeout, like so: var cookieCatFilter = $('#category_filter').data('curr_filter');
  var cookieTopicFilter = $('#topic_filter').data('curr_filter');
  var cookieSortFilter = $('#sort_by_filter').data('curr_filter');
  
  console.log(cookieCatFilter); 
  console.log(cookieTopicFilter); 
  console.log(cookieSortFilter); 
  
  setTimeout(function(){ 
  console.log(cookieCatFilter); 
  console.log(cookieTopicFilter); 
  console.log(cookieSortFilter); 
  }, 3000);

but yielded the same answer when trying to change the topic.

Comment: Where did you put the delay?

Comment: After the if statement, with all that cookie logic within the delay function

Comment: Try it before the if?

Comment: Just tried, now I got 4 instances of the same variables :/ (before the if -> delay, after the if -> delay).  

The point of the if statement is to clean out the html of the filters, so it wouldn't make sense to put it before.